# Regarding Encoding the ~ charecter in javascript

Tags: javascript

can you please tell me the how can we encode the ~ character in javascript..

i am trying with the encodeURIComponet.but that character is not encoding...

and also , how can we encode < and  > characters in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The reason encodeURIComponent isn't encoding them is that they don't need to be encoded in a URI.

You can use

```
escape('~ < > ');
```

if you really want to